# Store S4 objects in data.frame or data.table

Tags: r, data.table, iteration, embedding, r-s4

I'm trying to put complex **S4** objects (generated with Seurat package) in **data.table** (I read that it was not possible to use a list or a data.frame, but I didn't find anything about the compatibility of data.table with S4 objects) depending on the **value of one** of their attribute with a function. 
These objects all come from a bigger object that I called dataset in the function I wrote:

```
 subsets_by_cluster <- function(dataset){
 nclust=data.table(cluster_ID=c(rep(NA,length(unique(dataset@active.ident)))))
 for (i in length(nclust)){
     nclust[i]=dataset[,dataset@active.ident==unique(dataset@active.ident)[i]] 
 }
 return(nclust)}
```

I was expecting getting a **data.table full of S4 objects**, with **one column** with as many **rows as number of different @active.ident** values (cluster IDs)
But when I run it on my original dataset, I get the error

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, 1, value = new("Seurat", assays = list( : replacement has 2965 rows, data has 1

I also tried to do it manually with this kind of line

`nclust[1]=dataset[,dataset@active.ident==unique(dataset@active.ident)[1]]`

but it didn't work either, prompting the error :

> type 'S4' cannot be coerced to 'logical'

Storing the subset in **a variable works** perfectly, but I would like my script be able do **handle different cluster numbers**. 
I was thinking about writing the files to read so they can then be read, but it seems far from being a optimal solution.

Do you have suggestions ?

Comment: I don't know the Seurat packge, but you can certainly make a `list` of S4 objects.

Comment: what is `dataset` is it one of these S4 objects? Or is it something else?

Comment: Thank you @JohnPaul, but I tried but it didn't work either, giving the error : 

> Error in `[.Seurat`(dataset, , dataset@active.ident == unique(dataset@active.ident)[i]) : 
  Incorrect number of logical values provided to subset cells

When I tried manually, I got the error : 

> implicit list embedding of S4 objects is deprecated

`typeof(dataset)` gives me "S4" as output, but I didn't created it myself

Comment: If you just do `dataset@active.ident` what do you get? A single value,a  vector, or something else?

Comment: `dataset@active.ident` gives an `integer` but it's like 5800 IDs and their associated cluster. For example, dataset@active.ident[50] returns me the ID of the 50th cell (i'm doing bioinformatics) and the name of its associated cluster

Answer (score 1):

First, creating a simple S4 class (taken from Hadley Wickham's [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s4.html))

```
setClass("Person", 
  slots = c(
    name = "character",
    age = "numeric"
  )
)
```

As @John Paul mentions, you can create a few and store them in a list

```
john <- new("Person", name = "John Smith", age = NA_real_)
jane <- new("Person", name = "Jane Smith", age = NA_integer_)

myPeeps <- list(john, jane)
```

Printing the list

```
> myPeeps
[[1]]
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] "John Smith"

Slot "age":
[1] NA


[[2]]
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] "Jane Smith"

Slot "age":
[1] NA
```

Since a `data.frame` is a special type of `list` and as we see above a `list` element can be an `S4` object, you can store them in a column as well. You just have to use the `I()` function

```
size <- 5

propsToMyPeeps <- data.frame(
  propsFrom = I(sample(myPeeps, size, replace = TRUE)),
  propsValue = sample.int(10, size, replace = TRUE),
  propsTo = I(sample(myPeeps, size, replace = TRUE))
)
```

By default, the `print` method for `data.frame` doesn't know how to coerce our `Person` to a character string so printing the data.frame will cause an error. But if you subset the column, you can see all the objects are there.

```
> print(propsToMyPeeps$propsTo)
[[1]]
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] "Jane Smith"

Slot "age":
[1] NA


[[2]]
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] "John Smith"

Slot "age":
[1] NA


[[3]]
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] "John Smith"

Slot "age":
[1] NA


[[4]]
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] "Jane Smith"

Slot "age":
[1] NA


[[5]]
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] "Jane Smith"

Slot "age":
[1] NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But my issue is that I firstly have to split my big "dataset" file in several (I don't know how many) smaller datasets, depending on the value of the @active.ident. If I isolate manually each subset (with two lines like ` subset1=dataset[,dataset@active.ident==unique(dataset@active.ident)[1]) `.
 I can effectively store them in a list (`list(subset1,subset2)`) but not iteratively through a function, which is what I'm looking to do

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
library(Seurat)
library(data.table)
data(pbmc_small)

nclust = data.table(cluster_ID=levels(Idents(pbmc_small)))
nclust$data = lapply(nclust$cluster_ID,function(i){
  pbmc_small[,Idents(pbmc_small)==i]
})
```

And they can be accessed:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(grobs=lapply(nclust$data,DimPlot),ncol=3)
```

[image]

```
   cluster_ID     data
1:          0 <Seurat>
2:          1 <Seurat>
3:          2 <Seurat>
```

the error in your code comes with first defining the column to be only NAs,and replacing them one at a time. And, it should be for `for(i in 1:nrow(nclust))` instead of `for(i in length(nclust))`

If you start by defining it as a list of NAs, it works:

```
subsets_by_cluster <- function(dataset){

 lvl = levels(Idents(dataset))
 nclust=data.table(
 cluster_ID = lvl,
 data=replicate(length(lvl),NA,simplify=FALSE)
 )
 for (i in 1:nrow(nclust)){
     nclust$data[[i]]=dataset[,Idents(dataset)==lvl[i]] 
 }
 return(nclust)}

subsets_by_cluster(pbmc_small)
   cluster_ID     data
1:          0 <Seurat>
2:          1 <Seurat>
3:          2 <Seurat>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @StupidWolf, that's exactly what I needed!